# Blocking queue and InterruptedException

Tags: java, queue, java.util.concurrent

I have a class A with a LinkedBlockingQueue as property. In one method of A, I call the LinkedBlockingQueue.put() method since I want to insert an item in the queue. But, if the queue is full, my thread will wait until space is available or until my thread is interrupted.

The problem is that even if my thread is interrupted, I want the item to be in the queue.

Is there a way to be sure that my item has been inserted in the queue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see is to call queue.put() in a loop. This way maybe

```
boolean added = false;

while ( !added){
    try{
        queue.put(value);
        added = true;
    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
        // do something if required

        // make sure to set the interrupted flag on the thread, since it was cleared
        // when the exception was thrown
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}

if(Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()){
    // you were previously interrupted before, so try to exit gracefully
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the IF statement?

Comment: Well, if your thread was interrupted, the correct behavior is to try to stop that thread as early as possible (that's what interrupting a thread is for). You do not want your thread to exit before you are sure the item is in the queue, but you also should respect the meaning of the InterruptedException you've previously received. It might not be relevant in your case, but that's what the last if statement is used for in my case.

Comment: Under which circumstances a thread that has been interrupted should exit? Why do you think we should understand from the exception that something "goes wrong" and that we need to prepare shutting down the thread?

Comment: An interrupted thread should stop "as soon as possible". That's the correct behavior. As the implementor, it is your job to know what "as soon as possible" means, and when it is acceptable to actually let the thread terminate.

Comment: Just to elaborate, it seems that in your case, "as soon as possible" means "as soon as my value has been added to that queue". Therefore, the code I provided make sure that the value is added to the queue, and then lets the thread terminate. In other cases, "as soon as possible" might be "as soon as this web request is finished", or "right now, but I really need this operation to be continued at a later time" in which case the threads state would need to be stored somewhere and picked up later by another thread.

Comment: When an InterruptedException is thrown the interrupted flag gets cleared, so Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted() will return false.  If you are going to ignore the interruption, you save the fact that it was interrupted in a boolean and then either throw an InterruptedException or reinterrupt the Thread.

Answer (score 3):

You have to decide whether you want to wait if the queue is full or not. You can't tell it to ignore the maximum length if you set it.

What you can do is slow the producer if the queue is too large instead.  This will allow you to "ignore" the maximum if you wish. e.g. on an interrupt.

Comment: Yes, I need to wait if the queue is full. But, as I understand from the JavaDoc, an InterruptedException may be thrown during waiting and in this case, the put() method is left and my item has not been inserted in the queue. What should I do in the caller code?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache that depends on your requirements. Generally, if your thread had been interrupted it means that something is going wrong in your application and your thread should stop processing. You could place the object in some storage location to be picked up by another thread or on application startup.

Comment: An InterruptedException does not mean that something went wrong in your application, it just means that some other thread has called Thread.interrupt() on the current thread. Typically this is done whenever your application wants to explicitly stop a thread. Calling Thread.interrupt() is the equivalent of telling the thread "please exit as fast as you can" (eg: because you were doing a lenghty background operation and the user wants to cancel it, or the JVM has been requested to shut down for some reason), and is in no way an indication that something is going wrong.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but provides workarounds.